# PRESTASHOP - How to hide module (or div) after user login

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

Good morning to everybody! 
I tried to write something in Smarty but the result has been really crapy.

I'm using the "Image slider for your homepage" module ... but I need that it disappears after the user login.

Please ... How can I do?!

Thanks

Comment: In your `.tpl`file:- `{if $logged}
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$('. your slider div class').hide();});</script>
{/if}`

Comment: if jquery library already added then skip first line

Comment: Hey Anant! Thanks for you reply. 

I tried your method but it doesn't works ... the site gives me back an Error Server 500. :(

Comment: what you tried can you put in your question?

Comment: Ok ... sorry.

As you said I added your line of code in the header.tpl ... that is file where is located the container.

Maybe I have to add in the file .tpl of the module?

Sorry but sometimes I get lost in themes ...

Answer (score 0):

You can override your module php file in the override/modules/{yourmodule}/{yourmodule}.php:

```
class {yourmodule}Override extends {yourmodule} {
    public function displayHomeTop($params){
        if($this->context->customer->id){
            return;
        }else{
            return parent::displayHomeTop($params);
        }
    }
}
```

You can replace the displayHomeTop method with you module hook.